# Getting monthly data from Full Year (FY) data in Pandas/Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, analytics

I have field that has data for full year (FY) revenue per operation.
I have to phase it based on number of months for the operation was live for current year. I have other fields like start-date, end-date and term in months.

```
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
OpNum ,Start-date,End-date,Term,FY REV
OP1, 2020-11-01,2022-10-30,24,12000
OP2, 2021-03-01,2023-03-31,25,15000
OP3, 2020-07-01,2021-05-31,11,20000"""))
```

I am doing following to divide it by 12 and then get monthly data

```
df['MTD REV'] = df['FY REV']/12
months = list(pd.Series(range(1,13)))
df['month'] = df.apply(lambda x: months, axis=1)
df1 = df.explode("month")
```

What I want is like below:
OP1 starts in 2020 and ends in 2022 so the FY REV will be divided by 12 and months will 1-12
OP2 starts in 2021 and ends in 2023 so the FY REV will be divided by 10 and months will be 3-12
OP3 starts in 2020 and ends in 2021 so the FY REV will be divided by 5 and months will be 1-5

for example:

| OpNum | Start-date | End-date | Term | FY REV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OP1 | 2020-11-01 | 2022-10-30 | 24 | 12000 |
| OP2 | 2021-03-01 | 2023-03-31 | 25 | 15000 |
| OP3 | 2020-07-01 | 2021-05-31 | 11 | 20000 |

Expected outcome:

| OpNum | Start-date | End-date | Term | month | MTD REV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OP1 | 2020-11-01 | 2022-10-30 | 24 | 1 | 1000 |
| OP1 | 2020-11-01 | 2022-10-30 | 24 | 2 | 1000 |
| OP1 | 2020-11-01 | 2022-10-30 | 24 | 3 | 1000 |
| OP1 | 2020-11-01 | 2022-10-30 | 24 | 4 | 1000 |
| OP1 | 2020-11-01 | 2022-10-30 | 24 | 5 | 1000 |
| OP1 | 2020-11-01 | 2022-10-30 | 24 | 6 | 1000 |
| OP1 | 2020-11-01 | 2022-10-30 | 24 | 7 | 1000 |
| OP1 | 2020-11-01 | 2022-10-30 | 24 | 8 | 1000 |
| OP1 | 2020-11-01 | 2022-10-30 | 24 | 9 | 1000 |
| OP1 | 2020-11-01 | 2022-10-30 | 24 | 10 | 1000 |
| OP1 | 2020-11-01 | 2022-10-30 | 24 | 11 | 1000 |
| OP1 | 2020-11-01 | 2022-10-30 | 24 | 12 | 1000 |
| OP2 | 2021-03-01 | 2023-03-31 | 25 | 3 | 1500 |
| OP2 | 2021-03-01 | 2023-03-31 | 25 | 4 | 1500 |
| OP2 | 2021-03-01 | 2023-03-31 | 25 | 5 | 1500 |
| OP2 | 2021-03-01 | 2023-03-31 | 25 | 6 | 1500 |
| OP2 | 2021-03-01 | 2023-03-31 | 25 | 7 | 1500 |
| OP2 | 2021-03-01 | 2023-03-31 | 25 | 8 | 1500 |
| OP2 | 2021-03-01 | 2023-03-31 | 25 | 9 | 1500 |
| OP2 | 2021-03-01 | 2023-03-31 | 25 | 10 | 1500 |
| OP2 | 2021-03-01 | 2023-03-31 | 25 | 11 | 1500 |
| OP2 | 2021-03-01 | 2023-03-31 | 25 | 12 | 1500 |
| OP3 | 2020-07-01 | 2021-05-31 | 11 | 1 | 4000 |
| OP3 | 2020-07-01 | 2021-05-31 | 11 | 2 | 4000 |
| OP3 | 2020-07-01 | 2021-05-31 | 11 | 3 | 4000 |
| OP3 | 2020-07-01 | 2021-05-31 | 11 | 4 | 4000 |
| OP3 | 2020-07-01 | 2021-05-31 | 11 | 5 | 4000 |

Comment: Does FY Rev  cover the period 01/01/2021 through 12/31/2021 or s0ome other period?

Comment: It has data for full year, and current year which is 2021 in this case.

Comment: So to be precise from 01/01/2001 through to 12/31/2021 inclusive?

Comment: Yes the complete year 01/01/2021 - 12/31/2021

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach:

Create `DF` with dates as `datetime`:

```
from io import StringIO
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
OpNum,Start-date,End-date,Term,FY REV
OP1, 2020-11-01,2022-10-30,24,12000
OP2, 2021-03-01,2023-03-31,25,15000
OP3, 2020-07-01,2021-05-31,11,20000"""),
                parse_dates=['Start-date','End-date'])
```

Create a `DateTimeIndex` for subsequent calculation:

```
tgt_yr = 2021
df['d_rng'] = \
    df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(start=x['Start-date'], end=x['End-date'], freq='M'), axis=1)
```

Do some calculations:

```
df['month_count'] = df['d_rng'].apply(lambda x: (x.year == tgt_yr).sum())
df['month_min'] = df['d_rng'].apply(lambda x: x[(x.year == tgt_yr)].min().month)
df['MTD REV'] = df['FY REV'] / df['month_count']
```

Repeat the rows for each `OpNum` to match the `month_count`:

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['month_count'])].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Fill in the month number:

```
df['month'] = df.groupby('OpNum').cumcount() + df['month_min']
```

Result:

```
df[['OpNum','Start-date','End-date','Term','month','MTD REV']]

   OpNum Start-date   End-date  Term  month  MTD REV
0    OP1 2020-11-01 2022-10-30    24      1   1000.0
1    OP1 2020-11-01 2022-10-30    24      2   1000.0
2    OP1 2020-11-01 2022-10-30    24      3   1000.0
3    OP1 2020-11-01 2022-10-30    24      4   1000.0
4    OP1 2020-11-01 2022-10-30    24      5   1000.0
5    OP1 2020-11-01 2022-10-30    24      6   1000.0
6    OP1 2020-11-01 2022-10-30    24      7   1000.0
7    OP1 2020-11-01 2022-10-30    24      8   1000.0
8    OP1 2020-11-01 2022-10-30    24      9   1000.0
9    OP1 2020-11-01 2022-10-30    24     10   1000.0
10   OP1 2020-11-01 2022-10-30    24     11   1000.0
11   OP1 2020-11-01 2022-10-30    24     12   1000.0
12   OP2 2021-03-01 2023-03-31    25      3   1500.0
13   OP2 2021-03-01 2023-03-31    25      4   1500.0
14   OP2 2021-03-01 2023-03-31    25      5   1500.0
15   OP2 2021-03-01 2023-03-31    25      6   1500.0
16   OP2 2021-03-01 2023-03-31    25      7   1500.0
17   OP2 2021-03-01 2023-03-31    25      8   1500.0
18   OP2 2021-03-01 2023-03-31    25      9   1500.0
19   OP2 2021-03-01 2023-03-31    25     10   1500.0
20   OP2 2021-03-01 2023-03-31    25     11   1500.0
21   OP2 2021-03-01 2023-03-31    25     12   1500.0
22   OP3 2020-07-01 2021-05-31    11      1   4000.0
23   OP3 2020-07-01 2021-05-31    11      2   4000.0
24   OP3 2020-07-01 2021-05-31    11      3   4000.0
25   OP3 2020-07-01 2021-05-31    11      4   4000.0
26   OP3 2020-07-01 2021-05-31    11      5   4000.0
```